# 400 Bad request when uploading image to Google Cloud storage using Python 3 Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to upload a image to cloud storage using `blob.upload_from_string` but I get a

> 400 Bad Request Error

I'm following [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/using-cloud-storage), but the difference is that I want to send a string instead of a file, and the string contains the image.

This is the function :

```py
def upload_image_file(self, file):
    """
    Upload the user-uploaded file to Google Cloud Storage and retrieve its
    publicly-accessible URL.
    """
    if not file:
        return None

    testImageString = "Python is interesting."
    arr = bytes(testImageString, 'utf-8')

    public_url = storage.upload_file(
        arr,
        "fileName.jpg",
        "jpg"
    )

    current_app.logger.info(
        "Uploaded file %s as %s.", file.filename, public_url)

    return public_url
```

and this is the function that is in the example that uploads the image this is the one that I call in this line `storage.upload_file(arr, "fileName.jpg", "jpg")`.

```py
def upload_file(file_stream, filename, content_type):
   """
   Uploads a file to a given Cloud Storage bucket and returns the public url
to the new object.
"""
_check_extension(filename, current_app.config['ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS'])
filename = _safe_filename(filename)

client = _get_storage_client()
bucket = client.bucket(current_app.config['CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET'])
blob = bucket.blob(filename)

blob.upload_from_string(
    file_stream,
    content_type=content_type)

url = blob.public_url

if isinstance(url, six.binary_type):
    url = url.decode('utf-8')

return url
```

I'm getting this error

> google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 POST
>   https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/image-buck-share/o?uploadType=multipart:
>   ('Request failed with status code', 400, 'Expected one of',
>   )

Here is the full error trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/myUser/Documents/MICROSERVICES/service-upload-img/env/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/myUser/Documents/MICROSERVICES/service-upload-img/env/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/myUser/Documents/MICROSERVICES/service-upload-img/env/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/myUser/Documents/MICROSERVICES/service-upload-img/env/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/myUser/Documents/MICROSERVICES/service-upload-img/env/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/myUser/Documents/MICROSERVICES/service-upload-img/env/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/myUser/Documents/MICROSERVICES/service-upload-img/main.py", line 17, in generate_image_v2
    return resource.generate_image(req)
  File "/home/myUser/Documents/MICROSERVICES/service-upload-img/service/imageGenerator.py", line 20, in generate_image
    transfersResponse = self.testSaveImageLocal(inputData)
  File "/home/myUser/Documents/MICROSERVICES/service-upload-img/service/imageGenerator.py", line 173, in testSaveImageLocal
    self.upload_image_file(output)
  File "/home/myUser/Documents/MICROSERVICES/service-upload-img/service/imageGenerator.py", line 195, in upload_image_file
    "jpg"
  File "/home/myUser/Documents/MICROSERVICES/service-upload-img/service/storage.py", line 66, in upload_file
    content_type=content_type)
  File "/home/myUser/Documents/MICROSERVICES/service-upload-img/env/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 1296, in upload_from_string
    predefined_acl=predefined_acl,
  File "/home/myUser/Documents/MICROSERVICES/service-upload-img/env/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 1200, in upload_from_file
    _raise_from_invalid_response(exc)
  File "/home/myUser/Documents/MICROSERVICES/service-upload-img/env/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 2089, in _raise_from_invalid_response
    raise exceptions.from_http_status(response.status_code, message, response=response)
google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/image-buck-share/o?uploadType=multipart: ('Request failed with status code', 400, 'Expected one of', <HTTPStatus.OK: 200>)
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Oct/2019 10:52:04] "POST /img/up/ser/generator/v2 HTTP/1.1" 500
```

Comment: 1) Content Type is wrong. 2) You are calling `storage.upload_file`, do you mean to call `upload_file`? 3) Error 400 means your request is probably malformed.

Comment: 2) yes storage.upload_file is where the function is, that's why I call storage.name_of_function , 
3) I know that I'm sending something wrong my guess is the string of the image, the file_stream

Comment: If the file_stream param was wrong you would have a Python exception. Cloud Storage does not care what the contents of the data are (binary, string, Unicode, ...). Your Content-Type is wrong. Fix that.

Comment: can you indicate in what line I'm setting the content type? I think that I'm setting in with "jpg"

Comment: The third parameter to `storage.upload_file`. Google link: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata#content-type . This should be `image/jpeg` for JPEG images. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types